# How to change the Width of Banner

Tags: jquery, css, width, banner

I have a banner on which he has width of 100%.
Would make (maybe with jQuery), when I clicked a button, the width of the banner to be 980px.

Does anyone know help me with this?

I tried this code but did not work. :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#botao").click(function() {
        $f(.fullwidthbanner).css("width","100%");
        }).click(function() {
        $(.fullwidthbanner).css("width","980px");
    })
})
</script>
```

In which class contains the element width is. Fullwidthbanner. PS: It is in a stylesheet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just have some code formatting to do... You are on the right track.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#botao").click(function() {
            $('.fullwidthbanner').css("width","980px");
    });
});
```

Comment: Some semicolons are missing at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#botao").click(function() {
     $('.fullwidthbanner').css("width","980px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(.fullwidthbanner)`  Quotes are missing!

Comment: I don't think variables can start with a special character.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#botao').click(function() {
     $('.fullwidthbanner').css('width', '980px');
  });
});
</script>
```

Don't forget the quotes in the jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

you have only to write a on click event liket this:
is betterfor the new version to use `.on` instead directly `.click`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xaGyc/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#botao").on("click",function() {
     $(".fullwidthbanner").css("width","980px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is .on better than .click?

Comment: .on is created to sustitute .live and .bind and I think that is a fast method It's a shorthands method. Now isn't important to use .on than .click but personally I think is better @ToniToniChopper

Answer (score 0):

Reffer to jQuery Docs [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) & .[height()](http://api.jquery.com/height)

**.width( value )**

**Description:** Set the CSS width of each element in the set of matched elements.

---

.width( **value** )

**value** An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer along with an optional unit of measure appended (as a string).

```
(function() {
  var modWidth = 50;
  $("div").one('click', function () {
    $(this).width(modWidth).addClass("mod");
  modWidth -= 8;
  });
})();
​
```

---

.width( **function(index, width)** )

**function(index, width)** A function returning the width to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old width as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

[HERE A DEMO JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZezzz/RSgy2/)